# pipenv shell Launching subshell in virtual environment… 'powershell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or

Tags: python, django, windows, powershell, pipenv

I am using Windows 10, and Visual Studio Code terminal (but I tried also Windows Powershell).

This is my location: `PS C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\MyProjectFolder>`

This was successful: `pip install --user pipenv`

This was successful: `pipenv install django`

At the end I get the message:

```
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

So I run: `pipenv shell` and get only this message:

```
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
'powershell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have searched for duplicate questions but could not find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Change your PATH variable to cmd.exe (which is located in the system32 folder)

Then use command {pipenv location} shell

This should fix the problem.

XD